# how do i check if the ctx is a private channel(dm channel)

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

essentially, i want this command to only be run in DMS, and not be activatable in the servers my bot is in, i know there is a decorator for checks but I'm not sure how to use it exactly, any help is appreciated

```py
class verify:
    def check():
        #something 

    @bot.command()
    @commands.check(check)
    async def verify(ctx):
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

Literally seconds after I wrote this, version 1.1.0 was released, which includes a built-in [`dm_only`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.dm_only) check

Original:

This is the opposite of the built-in [`guild_only`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.guild_only) check, which [is defined as](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/discord/ext/commands/core.py#L1533):

```
def guild_only():
    """A :func:`.check` that indicates this command must only be used in a
    guild context only. Basically, no private messages are allowed when
    using the command.
    This check raises a special exception, :exc:`.NoPrivateMessage`
    that is inherited from :exc:`.CheckFailure`.
    """

    def predicate(ctx):
        if ctx.guild is None:
            raise NoPrivateMessage()
        return True

    return check(predicate)
```

So a `dm_only` check would look something like

```
class NoGuildMessage(CheckFailure):
    pass

def dm_only():
    def predicate(ctx):
        if ctx.guild is not None:
            raise NoGuildMessage()
        return True

    return check(predicate)
```